# how to make until successful as synchronous to retry mechanism for FTP Outbound in mule 3.4.2

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I used retry mechanism for outbound FTP by using Untill successful. It is working fine but it is working as asynchronously in mule 3.4.2.I have seen synchronous option is avaliable in 3.5. is it possible to make untill successful scope working as synchronous in 3.4.2 version? if possible could u please provide me the solution? or else any other solution to use retry mechanism for outbound FTP?

```
<until-successful objectStore-ref="objectStore" maxRetries="3" secondsBetweenRetries="1" doc:name="Until Successful">
    <ftp:outbound-endpoint host="10.10.10.10" port="7055" path="#[flowVars.FTPConfig.getPath()]" user="user" password="password" outputPattern="${filename}" responseTimeout="20000" doc:name="FTP" connector-ref="FTP"/>
</until-successful>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to make `until-successful` synchronous in Mule 3.4. You need to upgrade to version 3.5, or even 3.6 which is available at this writing.

Alternatively, you could remove `until-successful` and use an inbound VM or JMS endpoint with transactional delivery to perform retries on the outbound FTP endpoint.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for ur reply. I have tried like using vm as outbound in a flow and i used sub flow in which i used vm as inbound and ftp as outbound and i enabled VM transacation in this..even though its not working. can we achieve retry mechanish using this..if yes could you please provide me a example xml config file to do that using VM..??

Comment: @ManirathnamGowd Create a new question and show what you've done so far, so we can help you.

Comment: Hi David as per your suggestion we have raised a new question wih whta we have done till now. Please refer below question..Thanks in advance :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30773112/how-to-achieve-retry-mechanism-for-ftp-outbound-end-point-using-vm-transaction